# Force xscreensaver to go fullscreen on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fullscreen, xscreensaver

I'm using xscreensaver on Ubuntu 12.04 instead of gnome-screensaver.
When xscreensaver activates, the unity top- and sidepanel are still visible.

Does anyone know how to force those to the background?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like an issue with Xorg, although there is a work around for it.

http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#screen-size

Comment: The strangest name for a workaround I've seen so far :) Awesome, thanks for your reply!